# Why did this happen in The Rise Of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I didn't understand why

> Kylo Ren & Leia’s body

disappeared at same time?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy StackExchange. Maybe if you edited your question, you would get fewer downvotes. Are you looking for an in-universe explanation? Are you asking if the scriptwriters had a reason in mind for the near simultaneous disappearances of these characters?

Comment: mother son relationship

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No real logical reason but more a symbolic one (The movie makes many of these "huh?" moments), this is to show that after all that Ben did Leia still loved him and wasn't ready to become one with the force because she still had to watch over her kid... after Ben was ready to pass on she became ready to do the same.